# How can I style this javascript button?

Tags: javascript

Hi I would like to know how I can style these buttons in Javascript in my quiz.
I can't figure out how to do that. Would be great if someone can help.
Sample code is below and full code is further below. I tried doing making the buttons a div but that did not work.
Would be great if someone can help.
Sample code is below and full code is further below.
thank you

```js
for(i=0; i < options.length; i++){
    document.getElementById("trivia").innerHTML += "<br><button onclick='checkAnswer(\""+options[i]+"\", this)'>" + options[i] + "</button>";
  }
}
```

```js
// This initialises a request to the trivia database API
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1&category=21&difficulty=easy&type=multiple";
var score = 0;
var livesTaken = 0;
var question;
var type;
var correctAnswer;
var incorrect1;
var incorrect2;
var incorrect3;

// This requests the data
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
var jsondata = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
getData(jsondata);
}
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

// This function is used to extract the received data
function getData(data) {
// This is the question:
question = data.results[0].question;

// This is the question type eg. multiple choice
type = data.results[0].type;

// This is the correct answer
correctAnswer = data.results[0].correct_answer;

// These are the three incorrect answers
incorrect1 = data.results[0].incorrect_answers[0];
incorrect2 = data.results[0].incorrect_answers[1];
incorrect3 = data.results[0].incorrect_answers[2];

// randomly select answer and other options and place in array
// then display elements from array on the buttons

var randoms = []; // an array to store unique random numbers
var random;

// loop runs four times...
for(i=0; i < 4; i++){
// generates a random number between 0 and 3
random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
// checks if random number already in array...
while(randoms.includes(random)){
// generates another random number
random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
}
// adds random number to array
randoms.push(random);
}


var options = [];
console.log(randoms);
options[randoms[0]] = correctAnswer;
options[randoms[1]] = incorrect1;
options[randoms[2]] = incorrect2;
options[randoms[3]] = incorrect3;

  
  console.log(options);

// This displays the question and answer options

document.getElementById("trivia").innerHTML = question;
  
  for(i=0; i < options.length; i++){
    document.getElementById("trivia").innerHTML += "<br><button onclick='checkAnswer(\""+options[i]+"\", this)'>" + options[i] + "</button>";
  }
}

function checkAnswer(selected, element){
console.log("User selected: " + selected);
console.log("The correct answer is: " + correctAnswer);
if(selected == correctAnswer){
  score++;
console.log("You got it right!");
element.style.background = "green";
setTimeout(function(){ 
  getNewQuestion();
}, 2000);
  
}
else{
  livesTaken ++;
console.log("Sorry, that's incorrect");
element.style.background = "red";
  if(livesTaken ==3){
  quizFailed();
  }else{
setTimeout(function(){ 
  getNewQuestion();
}, 450);
  }
}
console.log(score)
console.log(livesTaken)
}



function getNewQuestion(){
    document.getElementById("score").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("score").style.float = "right";
    document.getElementById("trivia").style.float = "left";
    document.getElementById("score").style.align = "right";
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "score:" + score;
    document.getElementById("trivia").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("endingText").style.display = "none";
  // This requests the data
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  var jsondata = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  getData(jsondata);
  }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
  } getNewQuestion()
  function quizFailed(){
    document.getElementById("endingText").style.display = "block"
    document.getElementById("score").style.display = "none"
    document.getElementById("trivia").style.display = "none"
    document.getElementById("endingText").innerHTML = "You have run out of lives, you scored " + score + " pretty bad ngl" + "  <button onClick = getNewQuestion() >click to restart</button>"
    
    score = 0;
    livesTaken = 0;
  }
  
  
    document.getElementById("score")
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Actualquiz.css">
    <title>Sport Quiz (Medium)</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <div id="trivia"></div>
    <div id ="endingText"></div>
    <div id ="score"></div>
  
  
  
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is the line where you create the btns

```
for(i=0; i < options.length; i++){
  document.getElementById("trivia").innerHTML += "<br><button onclick='checkAnswer(\""+options[i]+"\", this)'>" + options[i] + "</button>";
}
```

I suggest you to opt for another way, something like this would be a bit better.

```
for(i=0; i < options.length; i++) {
    let btn = document.createElement("button");
    // You can now style it like so
    btn.style.backgroundColor = "blue" // This is an example, you can use any css styling.
    btn.style.padding: 0.7rem 2rem;
    btn.style.color = "white";
    btn.style.marginTop = ".4rem";
    btn.setAttribute("onclick", `checkAnswer("${options[i]}", this)`);
    btn.innerHTML = options[i];
    let br = document.createElement("br");
    document.getElementById("trivia").append(br, btn); // You can now use the trivia div as a container for the generated button and your br
    }
}
```

But as you can see there's a lot of extra code to just style the button, so what I'd do is create a class with the preferred stylings, and apply it in the js, like so:

*JS file*

```
for(i=0; i < options.length; i++) {
    let btn = document.createElement("button");
    let br = document.createElement("br");

    btn.classList.add("trivia-btn");  // We're adding the class here
    btn.setAttribute("onclick", `checkAnswer("${options[i]}", this)`);
    btn.innerHTML = options[i];
    
    document.getElementById("trivia").append(br, btn); // You can now use the trivia div as a container for the generated button and your br
    }
}
```

*CSS file*

```
.trivia-btn {
  background-color: "blue";
  padding: 0.7rem 2rem;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 0.4rem;
}
```

My css example is a bit ugly but of course you can choose any css styling you want, or a framework to use premade classes.

Comment: One more question is it possible to change the colour of the button itself not just the text?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, background-color = the btn background color.
color = font/text color.